# difference between libevent and libevent-dev

Tags: libevent, libev

I am wondering as to what are the differences between libevent and libevent-dev.
So, I have installed libevent from source (stable version 2.0.21) - and I am not really able to find the sources for libevent-dev. Is libevent-dev not a separate package?
Do I not need libevent-dev if I have installed libevent stable from source?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you refer to the Debian packages. All -dev packages in debian provide the headers and static libraries (.a) needed to compile a program against the corresponding library. while the non -dev package provides the dynamic libraries (*.so), the man pages and so on.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay in replying! You were correct :)